# Можно ли вычесть из вектора вектор?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

я не знаю, не понимаю просто как реализовать данное задание.

Разработайте законченную программу, в которой с помощью подходящих конструкторов создайте три вектора v1, v2, v3 с элементами целого типа, размерами соответственно 5, 7, 6 и одинаковыми значениями элементов соответственно 1, 2, 3. Выведите на экран размеры векторов, значения их элементов и выполните присваивание v3=v2-v1. После этого вновь выведите на экран размеры векторов и значения их элементов.

Может там вместо - должно быть =, или можно все таки реализовать вычитание?

```
// laba9.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "russian");
    vector<int> v1(5,1), v2(7,2), v3(6,3);
    cout << "Число элементов в V1: " << v1.size() << endl;
    cout << "Элементы в V1: ";
    for(int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++)
        cout << v1[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Число элементов в V2: " << v2.size() << endl;
    cout << "Элементы в V2: ";
    for(int i=0; i<v2.size(); i++)
        cout << v2[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Число элементов в V3: " << v3.size() << endl;
    cout << "Элементы в V3: ";
    for(int i=0; i<v3.size(); i++)
        cout << v3[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, натолкните на мысль, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Садимся и пишем свой собственный оператор, типа

```
vector<int> operator-(const vector<int>&a, const vector<int>&b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
        throw("a.size() != b.size()"); // Или как-то иначе обработать разные размеры
    vector<int> c(a.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        c[i] = a[i] - b[i];
    return c;
}
```

Все. Осталось применить :)